# i want to create a 3D engine but i have problems with finding the formula

Tags: c, 3d, arduino, formula

i want to create a mini 3D engine. i have to put the code below in a single formula or if-statements with a resolution of 0.01. but i can't find a way to do that. maybe someone here can help me?

```
0 = 0.00
45 = 0.50
90 = 1.00
135 = 0.50
180 = 0.00
225 = 0.50
270 = 1.00
315 = 0.50
360 = 0.00
```

can this be calculated with a single formula or with if statements?

here is my code(i know its trash, i'm just experimenting a little bit)

```
int circX(float pi,int radius,int angle){
  float angleRad = (angle%360) / (180 / pi);

  return (radius * cos(angleRad));
}

int circY(float pi,int radius,int angle){
  float angleRad = (angle%360) / (180 / pi);

  return (radius * sin(angleRad));
}

void rotCube(int angleX,int angleY,int angleZ,byte state) {

  float pi = 3.141592;

  int x = 8;
  int y = 4;

  int x1 = 8;
  int y1 = 12;

  float rX = ?;
  float rY = ?;
  float rZ = ?;

  float flat = .5;

  int X0,X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,X7;
  int Y0,Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4,Y5,Y6,Y7;

  X0 = (circX(pi,7,(angleX))*.5+4);
  Y0 = (circY(pi,7,(angleX))+4);

  X1 = circX(pi,7,(angleX))*.5-4;
  Y1 = circY(pi,7,(angleX))+4;

  X2 = circX(pi,7,(angleX)+90)*.5-4;
  Y2 = circY(pi,7,(angleX)+90)+4;

  X3 = circX(pi,7,(angleX)+90)*.5+4;
  Y3 = circY(pi,7,(angleX)+90)+4;

  X4 = circX(pi,7,(angleX)+270)*.5+4;
  Y4 = circY(pi,7,(angleX)+270)-4;

  X5 = circX(pi,7,(angleX)+270)*.5-4;
  Y5 = circY(pi,7,(angleX)+270)-4;

  X6 = circX(pi,7,(angleX)+180)*.5-4;
  Y6 = circY(pi,7,(angleX)+180)-4;

  X7 = circX(pi,7,(angleX)+180)*.5+4;
  Y7 = circY(pi,7,(angleX)+180)-4;



  X0 = circX(pi,7,(angleY));
  Y0 = circY(pi,7,(angleY))+4;

  X1 = circX(pi,7,(angleY)+90);
  Y1 = circY(pi,7,(angleY)+90)+4;

  X2 = circX(pi,7,(angleY)+90);
  Y2 = circY(pi,7,(angleY)+90)+4;

  X3 = circX(pi,7,(angleY));
  Y3 = circY(pi,7,(angleY))+4;

  X4 = circX(pi,7,(angleY)+270);
  Y4 = circY(pi,7,(angleY)+270)-4;

  X5 = circX(pi,7,(angleY)+180);
  Y5 = circY(pi,7,(angleY)+180)-4;

  X6 = circX(pi,7,(angleY)+180);
  Y6 = circY(pi,7,(angleY)+180)-4;

  X7 = (circX(pi,7,(angleY)+270));
  Y7 = (circY(pi,7,(angleY)+270)-4);



  X0 = circX(pi,7,(angleZ));
  Y0 = circY(pi,7,(angleZ))*flat;

  X1 = circX(pi,7,(angleZ)+90);
  Y1 = circY(pi,7,(angleZ)+90)*flat;

  X2 = circX(pi,7,(angleZ)+180);
  Y2 = circY(pi,7,(angleZ)+180)*flat;

  X3 = circX(pi,7,(angleZ)+270);
  Y3 = circY(pi,7,(angleZ)+270)*flat;

  X4 = circX(pi,7,(angleZ));
  Y4 = circY(pi,7,(angleZ))*flat;

  X5 = circX(pi,7,(angleZ)+90);
  Y5 = circY(pi,7,(angleZ)+90)*flat;

  X6 = circX(pi,7,(angleZ)+180);
  Y6 = circY(pi,7,(angleZ)+180)*flat;

  X7 = circX(pi,7,(angleZ)+270);
  Y7 = circY(pi,7,(angleZ)+270)*flat;

  matrix.drawLine(X0+x,Y0+y, X1+x,Y1+y, state);
  matrix.drawLine(X1+x,Y1+y, X2+x,Y2+y, state);
  matrix.drawLine(X2+x,Y2+y, X3+x,Y3+y, state);
  matrix.drawLine(X3+x,Y3+y, X0+x,Y0+y, state);

  matrix.drawLine(X4+x1,Y4+y1, X5+x1,Y5+y1, state);
  matrix.drawLine(X5+x1,Y5+y1, X6+x1,Y6+y1, state);
  matrix.drawLine(X6+x1,Y6+y1, X7+x1,Y7+y1, state);
  matrix.drawLine(X7+x1,Y7+y1, X4+x1,Y4+y1, state);

  matrix.drawLine(X0+x,Y0+y, X4+x1,Y4+y1, state);
  matrix.drawLine(X1+x,Y1+y, X5+x1,Y5+y1, state);
  matrix.drawLine(X2+x,Y2+y, X6+x1,Y6+y1, state);
  matrix.drawLine(X3+x,Y3+y, X7+x1,Y7+y1, state);
  }
```

Comment: **Roughly** `sin(x)/2 + 0.5` by the looks of it, or easier, `abs(sin(x))`

Comment: The upper Block is neither named nor explained in here- what should that be- example output of - what?

Comment: @RuDevel that is what the formula needs to do but in a higher resolution

Comment: Google for the "Circle Equation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your function has a period of 180, do you can take the input value and mod 180 first of all:

```
x = x % 180;
```

Then you need to handle the fact that it decreases from 90-180:

```
if(x > 90)
   x = 180 - x;
```

x will now be a value between 0 and 90. You can scale and convert to float:

```
float value = (float)x / 90.0f;
```

In function form:

```
float getValue(int x)   
{
    if(x < 0) // check for negatives (may not be necessary if you never pass them in)
       x = -x;  // your function is symmetrical about 0 so we can just negate
    x %= 180;
    if(x > 90)
       x = 180 - x;
    return (float)x / 90.0f;
}
```